# Chamar methodos de outra classe

Tags: android, classes, objetos, sql-insert, onclick

No caso preciso chamar um método de outra classe para realizar uma inserção no banco de dados e tenho que passar um objeto do tipo `Usuario` como parâmetro

### Código:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.usuario);

    Button btn_gravar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_gravar);

    EditText nome_usuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_nome);
    EditText sexo_usuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_sexo);
    EditText telefone_usuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_telefone);
    EditText datanascimento_usuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_datanasc);
    EditText datacadastro_usuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_datacad);
    EditText cidade_usuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_cidade);
    EditText endereco_usuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_endereco);
    EditText cpf_usuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_cpf);
    EditText rg_usuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_rg);
    EditText email_usuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_email);

    final Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
            usuario.nome = nome_usuario;
            usuario.sexo = sexo_usuario;
            usuario.telefone = telefone_usuario;
            usuario.datanascimento = datanascimento_usuario;
            usuario.datacadastro = datacadastro_usuario;
            usuario.cidade = cidade_usuario;
            usuario.endereco = endereco_usuario;
            usuario.cpf = cpf_usuario;
            usuario.rg = rg_usuario;
            usuario.email = email_usuario;

    btn_gravar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Passando parâmetros da intent para o obj usuário
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Você foi cadastrado com sucesso!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                CrudUsuario crudusuario;
                crudusuario = new CrudUsuario(usuario);
                crudusuario.insert(usuario);



        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como esse método está declarado na outra classe? você não quer instanciar ela no seu código? Por que o jeito mais "correto" é você declarar uma instancia da classe aí dentro.

Caso não queira instanciar um jeito é você declarar o método como estático lá na classe em que o método está escrito, aí não precisa declarar a classe, só precisa do importe mesmo. Claro que lá do outro lado ele tem que estar pronto pra receber um objeto como parâmetro.

Comment: O objeto deve alimentar o metodo da Classe CrudUsuário
public void insert(Usuario usuario)
{
  //Minha logica
}

Comment: Que erro dá?  
Lembrando que se você passa um objeto usuário como parâmetro lá do outro lado a classe CrudUsuário  tem que estar preparada pra instanciar o objeto Usuario.